# c# text difference

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two words:
Source:    John
ConvertTo: Jack

and I want to show the effect of convert all letters from "Source" at the same time to the "ConvertTo" word. I already create a program to accomplish that but processing one letter at a time, to show the effect I use Threads, the thing is that to process all letters at the same time I suppose I need one thread per letter, and every thread will call the same function that process the letter, and I use global variables.

Here is the code (works only for texts with same lenght):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        lblResult.Text = "";
        lblResult2.Text = "";            
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Process));            
    }

    int movement = 0;
    string CumulateText;
    private void Process(object stateinfo)
    {
        int value;
        int operation; //0->[+] 1->[-]
        CumulateText = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= textBox1.Text.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text[i] != ' ')                
            {
                value = (char)textBox1.Text[i] - (char)textBox2.Text[i];
                if (value >= 0)
                    operation = 1;
                else
                    operation = 0;

                for (int ii = 0; ii <= Math.Abs(value); ii++)
                {
                    if (operation == 1)
                        movement = (char)textBox1.Text[i] - ii;
                    else
                        movement = (char)textBox1.Text[i] + ii;

                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowMovement));
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
            }
            CumulateText += textBox2.Text[i].ToString();                
        }
    }

    private void ShowMovement(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        lblResult.Text = CumulateText + Convert.ToString((char)movement);            
    }
```

I hope I made myself understood.
please any advise to accomplish that.
thanks

To clarify more what I want to accomplish here is an example:
Source:    John
ConvertTo: Jack

J - same          J
o - decrease till a (o, n, m, ..., a)
h - decrease till c (h, g, f, ..., c)
n - decrease till k (n, m, l, k)

Comment: "and I want to show the effect of convert all letters from "Source" at the same time to the "ConvertTo" word" - I'm sorry, I can't understand you. Please clarify.

Comment: Strings are immutable you can't 'replace' multiple letters in a string at the same time, you have to delete the old string and replace it with a new one every time. If you want to avoid this by magically replacing them 'at the same time' you should use a Stringbuilder and do it sequentionally instead.

Comment: thanks MrFox, if you take a look at the code you can realize that I make some work with the string so I can transform the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had to do something similar for a small little project I was working on for fun.

I do not see why you would need to create a thread for each letter to create a transition between two words unless I'm not understanding what you are pretending to do correctly.

Check and study the following code, see if its any help:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TextTranstition transition = new TextTranstition();
        transition.TransitionFinished += TransitionTicked;
        transition.TransitionTicked += TransitionTicked;
        transition.StartTransition("AmazingWordTransition", "MyNewWordAppearing", 100);
        Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void TransitionTicked(object sender, TranstitionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write(e.TransitionText);
    }
}

public class TranstitionEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly string transitionText;
    public string TransitionText { get { return this.transitionText; } }

    public TranstitionEventArgs(string transitionText)
    {
        this.transitionText = transitionText;
    }
}


public class TextTranstition
{
    private struct StartInfo
    {
        public StartInfo(string initialText, string finalText, int timeStep)
        {
            this.initialText = initialText;
            this.finalText = finalText;
            this.timeStep = timeStep;
        }

        private readonly string initialText;
        public string InitialText { get { return this.initialText; } }

        private readonly string finalText;
        public string FinalText { get { return this.finalText; } }

        private readonly int timeStep;
        public int TimeStep { get { return this.timeStep; } }
    }

    public EventHandler<TranstitionEventArgs> TransitionFinished;
    public EventHandler<TranstitionEventArgs> TransitionTicked;

    public void StartTransition(string initialText, string finalText, int timeStep)
    {
        StartInfo startInfo = new StartInfo(initialText, finalText, timeStep);
        Thread t = new Thread(startTransition);
        t.Start(startInfo);
    }

    private void startTransition(object info)
    {
        StartInfo startInfo = (StartInfo)info;
        string initialText = startInfo.InitialText;
        string finalText = startInfo.FinalText;

        if (initialText.Length < finalText.Length)
        {
            initialText = initialText.PadRight(finalText.Length);
        }

        if (TransitionTicked != null) TransitionTicked(this, new TranstitionEventArgs(initialText));

        while ((initialText = transition(initialText, finalText)) != finalText)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(startInfo.TimeStep);
            if (TransitionTicked != null) TransitionTicked(this, new TranstitionEventArgs(initialText));
        }

        if (TransitionFinished != null) TransitionFinished(this, new TranstitionEventArgs(finalText));
    }

    private string transition(string initialText, string finalText)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(finalText.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < finalText.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = initialText[i];
            int charCode = (int)c;

            if (c != finalText[i])
            {
                if (charCode == 122 || charCode==32) charCode = 65;
                else if (charCode == 90) charCode = 97;
                else
                {
                    charCode += 1;
                }
            }

            b.Append((char)charCode);
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's awesome and complex too, exactly what I was looking for, now I have to understand it :] thanks a lot

Comment: @Somebody: Glad its useful. Take into account that the current implementation only works for `'a'` to `'z'`, `'A'` to `'Z'` and `' '`. You can modify that changing the `char` shift logic in `transition()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use BackgroudWorker for this kind of stuff.

Comment: My main concern here is create multiples threads (one per letter) and call the same function that makes the letter transformation till the corresponding one in "ConvertTo" word, and they gonna use the same global variable in this case the specific letter to convert.